# Как можно закодировать картинку в base64 на Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, base64

Как можно закодировать картинку в base64 на Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас интересует вопрос как перевести байты в base64 строку, то в интернете полно вариантов реализаций. Правда, многие из них с ошибками :)
Вот мой работающий вариант:

```
function EncodeBase64(const Input: TBytes): string;
const
  Base64: array[0..63] of Char =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

  function Encode3Bytes(const Byte1, Byte2, Byte3: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[((Byte1 shl 4) or (Byte2 shr 4)) and $3F]
      + Base64[((Byte2 shl 2) or (Byte3 shr 6)) and $3F]
      + Base64[Byte3 and $3F];
  end;

  function EncodeLast2Bytes(const Byte1, Byte2: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[((Byte1 shl 4) or (Byte2 shr 4)) and $3F]
      + Base64[(Byte2 shl 2) and $3F] + '=';
  end;

  function EncodeLast1Byte(const Byte1: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[(Byte1 shl 4) and $3F] + '==';
  end;

var
  i, iLength: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  iLength := Length(Input);
  i := 0;
  while i < iLength do
  begin
    case iLength - i of
      3..MaxInt:
        Result := Result + Encode3Bytes(Input[i], Input[i+1], Input[i+2]);
      2:
        Result := Result + EncodeLast2Bytes(Input[i], Input[i+1]);
      1:
        Result := Result + EncodeLast1Byte(Input[i]);
    end;
    Inc(i, 3);
  end;
end;
```

Бывают различия в кодировании последних 2-х или одного байта (когда число байт не делится без остатка на 3). Уточняйте как их вам нужно закодировать.

Если вас интересует как из картинки получить байты, то для этого есть много способов. Создайте отдельный вопрос и уточняйте там условия.

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил несколько функций, самая быстрая из них из библиотеки Sha_Strings,

можно почитать здесь 
http://www.delphimaster.net/view/15-1163507354/0-39

Answer (score 0):

Если есть установленные компоненты Indy - можно воспользоваться функционалом, который есть в модуле idGlobal:

```
uses
  idGlobal;

function DecodeBase64(const AText: string): string;
begin
  Result := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(AText);
end;

function EncodeBase64(const AText: string): string;
begin
  Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(AText);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Иной раз лучше поздно, чем никогда.

Как вариант, для Delphi 10.2 Tokyo несколько потенциально полезных функций (Base64) приведены здесь:

https://roamer55.ru/main_programming/delphi/delphi_10_2_vcl/d10_funcs_dirfiles/d10_funcs_files_base64/

Может быть кому-то пригодится...

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)